# how to keep values when converting character to factor in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, rbind

So I am working with this matrix (see below) on R where you have the individuals and the the number of times they fought on Left,Right and total fight. I would like to do ANOVA to see the difference in number of fights per individuals. However I cannot use the column with the names so I need to add it and that's when I have a problem:

```
          Left Right Total
DarkMale    0     1     1   
Melman      5     2     7     
Polp        0    12    12       
Sun        10     1    11        
Kevin       0    11    11      
McFly       0    30    30      
Lovely     36     0    36     
Aquarius    0    30    30    
Kenny       0    23    23       
Lethabo    16     0    16     
Charlie     0     3     3    


Indv=rbind("DarkMale","Melman","Polp","Sun","Kevin","McFly","Lovely","Aquarius","Kenny","Lethabo","Charlie")
tab=cbind(tab,Total,Indv)
colnames(tab)=c("Left","Right","Total","Individuals")
```

I did this but then it converters the rest of table in Character which I cannot use either. 
I have tried `testtab=as.data.frame(tab,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`
which got rid of the "" in the table but still keeps all values in character. 
How can I convert the table by keeping these values (see below) but with it being integer or factor that I could use for anova?

```
           Left Right Total Individuals
DarkMale    0     1     1    DarkMale
Melman      5     2     7      Melman
Polp        0    12    12        Polp
Sun        10     1    11         Sun
Kevin       0    11    11       Kevin
McFly       0    30    30       McFly
Lovely     36     0    36      Lovely
Aquarius    0    30    30    Aquarius
Kenny       0    23    23       Kenny
Lethabo    16     0    16     Lethabo
Charlie     0     3     3     Charlie
```

Cheers

Comment: `tab[, 1:3] <- lapply(tab[, 1:3], as.numeric)`  converts character to numeric

Comment: I think you are deeply confused regarding what kind of data an ANOVA needs. In fact, you don't seem to know which statistical technique you should use.

Answer (score 3):

We need to first convert to `data.frame` and then create a column from the row names

```
d1 <- transform(as.data.frame(m1), Individuals = row.names(m1))
```

Using `cbind` on a `matrix` with a `character` element/elements convert the whole matrix to `character` as `matrix` can hold only a single class.  Afterwards, if we convert to `data.frame`, the class remains as such or change to `factor` depending on whether `stringsAsFactors` is `FALSE/TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it. I generated a `matrix` to start with what you are starting with, then transformed it into a `dataframe`. For more compact solution use `transform` as mentioned in akrun solution.

```
tab <- matrix(data =c(1:33) , nrow = 11, ncol = 3)
df <- as.data.frame(tab)

Indv <- c("DarkMale","Melman","Polp","Sun","Kevin","McFly","Lovely","Aquarius","Kenny","Lethabo","Charlie")
colnames <- c("Left","Right","Total","Individuals")

df[4] <- Indv

rownames(df) <- Indv
colnames(df) <- colnames
# 
#           Left Right Total Individuals
# DarkMale    1    12    23    DarkMale
# Melman      2    13    24      Melman
# Polp        3    14    25        Polp
# Sun         4    15    26         Sun
# Kevin       5    16    27       Kevin
# McFly       6    17    28       McFly
# Lovely      7    18    29      Lovely
# Aquarius    8    19    30    Aquarius
# Kenny       9    20    31       Kenny
# Lethabo    10    21    32     Lethabo
# Charlie    11    22    33     Charlie
```